# Is there a setting to make a Bixby capsule display properly in BOTH portrait and landscape?

Tags: orientation, display, bixby

My Bixby capsule looks fine in portrait mode, but does not resize properly when the phone is rotated to landscape mode

researched all Bixby Studio docs

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you raise a Feature Request for Bixby to handle landscape mode better and/or provide developers a way to define their views separately in [our community](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests). This forum is open to other Bixby developers who can upvote it, leading to more visibility within the community and with the Product Management team.